# Phonegap Camera Timestamp

Tags: cordova, plugins, camera

I'm using the phonegap camera plugin, and when the image is taken its saved at the back of my gallery, how do i get it saved with a time and date so its at the front of my gallery i'm using phonegap 2.9.0

```
    var pictureSource;   // picture source
    var destinationType; // sets the format of returned value

    // Wait for device API libraries to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);

    // device APIs are available
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        pictureSource=navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
        destinationType=navigator.camera.DestinationType;
    }

    // Called when a photo is successfully retrieved
    //
    function onPhotoDataSuccess(imageData) {
      // Uncomment to view the base64-encoded image data
      // console.log(imageData);

      // Get image handle
      //
      var smallImage = document.getElementById('smallImage');

      // Unhide image elements
      //
      smallImage.style.display = 'block';

      // Show the captured photo
      // The inline CSS rules are used to resize the image
      //
      smallImage.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
    }

    // Called when a photo is successfully retrieved
    //
    function onPhotoURISuccess(imageURI) {
      // Uncomment to view the image file URI
      // console.log(imageURI);

      // Get image handle
      //
      var largeImage = document.getElementById('largeImage');

      // Unhide image elements
      //
      largeImage.style.display = 'block';

      // Show the captured photo
      // The inline CSS rules are used to resize the image
      //
      largeImage.src = imageURI;
    }

    // A button will call this function
    //
    function capturePhoto() {
  // Take picture using device camera and retrieve image as base64-encoded string
  navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail,{
          quality : 25, 
          destinationType : Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI, 
          sourceType : Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA, 
          allowEdit : true,
          encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
          targetWidth: 500,
          targetHeight: 500,
          popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
          saveToPhotoAlbum: true });
}
    // A button will call this function
    //

    // Called if something bad happens.
    //
    function onFail(message) {
      alert('Failed because: ' + message);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the dates are correct after rebooting the phone.
This is a known issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-6640

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you have figured out the issue, but if you change launchMode to Single Instance it will work in 3.6.3. I have the same problem. But it now saves to sd card for some reason. But the time stamp is fixed.